# Make a piece of code work inside a function and inside a class

Tags: php, mysql

Basically the code inside the displayCharityList () works. I decided to put that code inside that function and that function inside a class and then tried to make it work by calling it afterwards....

Somehow it not pulling the data from the database. The query works inside the function but not in the __contruct

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong plz?

Thank you

```
<?php 
// Connection setup


class charity {
public $h;

        function __construct () {
            $c = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=seafarer_v2','seafarer_user','supp0rt1243');
            $h = $c->query('SELECT * FROM mnwg_charities')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $this->$h = $this->h;
            $this->displayCharity = $this->displayCharityList();
        }


    Public function displayCharityList(){

        echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Contact</th><th>Post code</th><th>Phone</th><th>Website</th><th>Email</th></tr>";
            foreach ($this->h as $r){

                      echo "<tr><td>";
                      echo $r['Name'];
                      echo "</td>";
                      echo "<td>";
                      echo $r['Contact'];
                      echo "</td>";
                      echo "<td>";
                      echo $r['Postcode'];
                      echo "</td>";
                      echo "<td><div class=\"phone\">";
                      echo "<img src=\"http://m.intertrustgroup.com/images/icon_phone.png\" style=\"margin-right:.5em\">{$r['Phone']}</br>";
                        if($r['Fax']){  echo "<img src=\"http://www.sliksvn.com/gfx/icon_fax.gif\" style=\"margin-right:.5em\">{$r['Fax']}";}
                      echo "</div></td>";
                      echo "<td>";
                      echo "<a href=\"{$r['Website']}\" target=\"_blank\"> Visit Website </a>";
                      echo "</td>";
                      echo "<td>";
                      echo "<a href=\"mailto:{$r['Email']}\">Send Email</a>";
                      echo "</td></tr>";

            }
           echo "</table>";
     }
 }


?>

<?php
$hola = new charity();
echo $hola->displayCharity(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some pointers, as the db connection is not related to the charity class but needed for query's you would pass the connection to the class, this is called dependency injection. Else as it stands on every initialization of the class, it is going to query the database, which is not needed if your going to access another method that does not require that query.
Also your `echo`ing and not `return`ing from the method, thats ok but you would need to place the call to the method specifically where you want placement. Its easier to return from the method and then use a single echo where you want placement. Hope it helps.

```
<?php 

class charity {

    function __construct (PDO $con) {
        $this->con = $con;
    }

    private function get_charities(){
        return $this->con->query('SELECT * FROM mnwg_charities')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function displayCharityList(){

        $return = "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Contact</th><th>Post code</th><th>Phone</th><th>Website</th><th>Email</th></tr>";
        foreach ($this->get_charities() as $r){
            $return .= "<tr><td>".$r['Name']."</td>";
            $return .= "</td>";
            $return .= "<td>";
            $return .= $r['Contact'];
            ...
            ...
        }
        $return .= "</table>";
        return $return;
    }
}

$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=seafarer_v2','seafarer_user','supp0rt1243');

$hola = new charity($con);

echo $hola->displayCharity();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing brackets

```
class charity

class charity () //which is wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

class Charity is not a function remove brackets.

It is a good habit to Capitalize class Names.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
 $hola = new charity();
 echo $hola->displayCharity(); //this line no needed
 ?>
```

second line no needed, because your calling displayCharity function with in the constructor function itself..
so no need to call again...
and then check your query is working correct...

Comment: thx, deleted. The query works when its inside the function, but not when it is in the construct

Comment: if i put the query inside but then the connect outside it is still not working.. i just declared the C as $this-c and put the query inside the function